# Recurrence relation of order $n$: $f(n) = \dfrac{1}{k-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} f(n-i)$.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I came across this recurrence relation while looking for a closed form for $S(n,k) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{i^n}{k^i}$.
After a few manipulations, I came across this recurrence relation: $f(n) = \dfrac{1}{k-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {n \choose i}f(n-i)$, where $f(n) = S(n, k)$ for a fixed $k$.

Any standard recurrence relation solving method doesn't work.

Comment: $S(n,k)$ is a *series*?

Comment: Yeah, it is, for a given $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Do you used that $S(n,1/x)$ is a power series?

Comment: I'm sorry. What did you mean? For convergence, $k > 1$.

Comment: Equivalently, $|x|<1$.

Comment: But I am not aware of any power series for that particular $S(n, k)$.

Comment: I will write an answer. TeX without preview is awkard.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $k=1/x$, your function is a power series:
$$
S(n,k)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\dfrac{i^n}{k^i}=
\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty{i^n}{x^i}=S(n,1/x)=f_n(x).
$$
Maybe you are interested only in the $k\in{\Bbb N}$ case, but power series are a *very* powerful tool.

EDIT:
$$f_0(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty{x^i}={1\over 1-x},
$$

$$
f_0'(x)=\cdots
$$

Comment: It still didn't answer how to solve my recurrence relation: $\dfrac{1}{k-1}f(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty {n\choose i}f(n-i)$. At least not in any way I understand.

Comment: Is an alternative method to the integer recurrence relation. If you are able to find a explicit formula/recurrence relation for the $f_n$ (being analytic functions=power series is important), $S(n,k)=f_n(1/k)$.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$
$f_0'(x) = \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty ix^{i-1}$.
Upto this, the pattern holds. However,
differentiating again,
$f_0"(x) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty i(i-1)x^{i-2}$, whereas, I would be interested in $\sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty i^2 x^{i-2}$, which can be manipulated to give $\sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty i^2 x^i$

Comment: $xf_0'(x)=\cdots$

Comment: I see. However, the subsequent derivatives of right hand side, after multiplying by $x$, become very complicated (e.g. for $\sum\limits_{i=0}i^2 x^n$, lhs is $x(f'(x) + xf''(x)) = x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)$, and so on.) I would be glad if you give a complete solution instead of hinting towards the solution! :-)

Comment: Only another idea: use the trick to find $S(n,k)$ in a few cases. This *can* suggest a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question yet I will give you another way of calculation $S(n,k)$. Since $i^n = \left.d^n_x \exp(x i) \right|_{x=0}$ we have:
\begin{equation}
S(n,k) = \left.\frac{d^n}{ d x^n} \frac{k}{k - \exp(x)}\right|_{x=0}
\end{equation}
Now we can caluculate the derivative for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ and we quickly see a pattern:
\begin{equation}
S(n,k) = \left.\sum\limits_{p=1}^{n+1} \frac{a^{(n)}_p}{(k - \exp(x))^p} \right|_{x=0}
\end{equation}
where the coefficients satisfy a following recursion relation:
\begin{equation}
a^{(n)}_p = \left.-p a_p^{(n-1)}\right|_{p\le n} + \left.k(p-1) a_{p-1}^{(n-1)}\right|_{p\ge 2} \quad\mbox{for}\quad p=1,2,\dots,n+1
\end{equation}
subject to $a^{(0)}_1 = 1$. We find closed form expressions for the coefficients:
\begin{eqnarray}
a^{(n)}_{n+1} &=& k^n n! \\
a^{(n)}_{n} &=& -\frac{1}{2} 
 k^{n-1} (n+1)! \\
\vdots
\end{eqnarray}
In principle one can keep work out expressions downwards, ie by taking $p=n,n-1,n-2,\dots..$ and using the results calculated before. The challenge is , however to find a closed form expression for $a^{(n)}_p$ for arbitrary values of $p$ and $n$.